# IntelliJ error with Scala function: "cannot resolve reference format with such signature"

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, intellij-14

IntelliJ complains about this code:

```
val document: Node // (initialized further up in the code)
val s: String = (new scala.xml.PrettyPrinter(80, 4)).format(document))
```

With the error:
Cannot resolve reference format with such signature

However - such a function exists. It has a default value for the second parameter and it seems IntelliJ isn't identifying it correctly.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure about that specific error you mention, but you have one parenthesis too many. You have:

```
val s: String = (new scala.xml.PrettyPrinter(80, 4)).format(document))
```

It should be:

```
val s: String = (new scala.xml.PrettyPrinter(80, 4)).format(document)
```

I just tried you code in `sbt` (once I made that correction) and it seems fine:

```
scala> import scala.xml._
import scala.xml._

scala> val document : Node = <test>blah</test>
document: scala.xml.Node = <test>blah</test>

scala> val s: String = (new PrettyPrinter(80, 4)).format(document)
s: String = <test>blah</test>
```